# Regex .search function to ignore name suffixes

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I created a regex definition that should read suffixes (eg., jr/sr/etc.) at the end of a name (space or comma) and then return the name if the suffix is in the name and then move on the next part of the if-then-else statement, which splits and does a reverse join on names with the last name, first name format.   I can't figure out what the problem is...but the re.search function is returning all values, instead of just the ones that are part of the name suffixes.  Please help!

```
d = {'Person': ['red robin, jr', 'bluejay, bluie', 'finch, mustard e', 'awing blackcrow' ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def separatetypes(name):
    if re.search(r'(?:\,|\s+(?:i|ii|iii|iv|jr|sr))*$', name): 
        return name
    elif ',' in name:
        namesplit = name.split(',',1)
        newname = str(namesplit[1]) + ' ' + str(namesplit[0])
        return newname
    else:
         return name
       
df['Person'] = df['Person'].apply(separatetypes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `*` in the pattern, which means "zero or more repetitions"; as a result, it's returning a match when it found zero suffixes.

The pattern you probably want is `r'(?:,|\s+(?:i|ii|iii|iv|jr|sr))$'` (without the `*` and omitting the unnecessary `\` before the comma) or `r'(?:,|\s+)(?:i|ii|iii|iv|jr|sr)$'` (which allows a suffix separated by comma, rather than a trailing comma).

As a general tool, sites like https://regex101.com/ (there are a bunch of them) can help develop regexes by explaining what's going on and by immediately showing results.